# python a function in another function?

Tags: function, python-3.x

I have the following function:

```
def second(first, a):
    # i want to return the results of first(a) in this function.
```

I just can't figure out how i can put values in (first(a)) without creating another function, or using lambda or any other modules? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "Put values in `first(a)`"? The "example" code seems lacking.. anyway, an object only needs to be [callable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python) to respond to `()`, functions (and constructors) normally have this property but it's not exclusive ..

Comment: I think the user wants to know how to **call** that function?

Comment: you question is not clear enought, first is already a function, which is defined somewhere right ? if yes why you can't just `return first(a)`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def first(a, *args, **kwargs):
...     print((a, args, kwargs))
...
>>> def second(func, a, *args, **kwargs):
...     return func(a, *args, **kwargs)
...
>>> second(first, 'hello', 'world', do='something')
('hello', ('world',), {'do': 'something'})
>>> second(int, 15)
15
>>> second(range, 2, 5)
range(2, 5)
```

You can omit *args or **kwargs part if you know you don't need additional arguments or keyword arguments for your functions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could call the function `first` passing as parameter `a`, and then `return` the value it returned:

```
def second(first, a):
    return first(a)
```