# Python - window_none() in matplotlib.mlab.specgram

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am performing a spectrogram using the function `matplotlib.mlab.specgram`
[see link](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.specgram). 
One of its arguments is the window function and the default one is the hanning window.

The signal to which I am applying the function is longer than the size of the block into which the signal is divided, that is the single slice of the spectrogram (I use NFFT = 512).

Here my question and my problem: I would like to change the window function from the default one -`hanning_window()`- to `window_none()`. One of the argument of `matplotlib.mlab.specgram` is indeed `window` to change the window function. But if I simply write among the arguments of the specgram function `window=matplotlib.mlab.window_none()` an error occurs since I am not specifying the array to which the window function must be applied. How can I specify this argument given the fact that the window function must be applied to several arrays of size NFFT and not to a single array, i.e. each block of length NFFT in which the signal is divided?

Comment: As a side note, this section of mlab just got a major overhaul.

Comment: As suggested by @Bonlenfum the right way to change the default window function is simply `window=matplotlib.mlab.window_none` and not `window=matplotlib.mlab.window_none()`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.specgram) you linked:

> matplotlib.mlab.specgram(x, NFFT=256, Fs=2, detrend=, window=, noverlap=128, pad_to=None, sides='default',
>   scale_by_freq=None)
>
> [...]
>
> window: callable or ndarray

Since it asks for `window` to be a callable (something like a function handle; see [What is a "callable" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111234/1643946)), it wants a *function*, and not the results of a function.  So give it

```
window=matplotlib.mlab.window_none, window=matplotlib.mlab.window_none, 
    <other args here as necessary>)
```

and it will use the (non-)windowing function.