# Is `type` really a function, or not?

Tags: python, function, object, python-3.x, types

First, I'm sorry if I'm asking something dumb, because I'm new to Python...
I was reading http://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types and saw that phrase:

> The type() function returns an object’s type (which is an object itself)

Of course, I decided to check this:

```
>>> def someFunction(x):
...     return x * x
...     
>>> type(someFunction)
<class 'function'>
>>> type(type)
<class 'type'>
```

So, looks like functions have the `function` type, but then why `type` function has a different type if it is a function? Or the docs are lying and it's not really a function?

Comment: It's a function implemented in C. And it is it's own type. Yes, it's turtles, all the way down!

Comment: `isinstance(type,object)`, `isinstance(object,type)`, and `isinstance(type,type)` are all `True`.  *Obviously*. :-)

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/1599111). It's about metaclasses, but it should make it clear to you what the two distinct functions (type checking and class factory) of `type()` in Python are used for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, `type` is a function, but it is implemented in C.

It also **has** to be it's own type, otherwise you could not do:

```
>>> def foo(): pass
... 
>>> type(foo)
<type 'function'>
>>> type(type)
<type 'type'>
>>> isinstance(type(foo), type)
True
```

e.g. you could not test if a type is a type, if `type`'s type was not `type` but `function`. With me still?

Technically speaking, `type` is a callable, and has two related roles to play. It is a metaclass (a class factory) and the base for all types in Python, **and** when called it produces a `type` instance (`<type 'function'>` is an instance of the `type` type).

The same applies to all types (including classes); call them and they produce a new instance of the given type.

Comment: I always though that type is a class

Comment: for me, it would be better if this couldn't be done...
when testing for another type (not `type`), there's a general way of writing second argument to `isinstance` function?

Comment: @SargeBorsch: and why would that be?

Comment: It looks dirty, and it's not general — `isinstance(foo, function)` won't work

Comment: @SargeBorsch: `isinstance(foo, types.FunctionType)` works just fine.

Comment: @SargeBorsch: there is no need for a built-in `function` function, but the type object still exists.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is there a type in `types` that corresponds to `type` type?

Comment: I looked through attributes of `types` module, but haven't found anything similar (although I found `FunctionType`)

Comment: @SargeBorsch the `types` module is for types that *aren't* directly available as builtins. So, `type` isn't in there, any more than `list`, `tuple` or `int` (among others).

Comment: @MartijnPieters there was no downvote I think, I just clicked in wrong place and immediately corrected

Comment: No, someone else did downvote this answer; I'd just love to know why they thought it deserved one.

Answer (score 3):

1. Note that in Python **[anything is object](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types)**. An object may be [callable](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#callable), i.e. work as function.
2. `type` is a [built-in **function**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=type#type), i.e. object of type that you can call as function. You can call it with one argument to get the type of an object. But there is also another use case.
3. `type` is a **[metaclass](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation)**, this means it is a type itself and can create classes (which are objects too).
4. All classes (and also metaclasses) are callable, this is one more reason why `type` is function. You can call it with three arguments to create a class.
5. `type` is basic built-in metaclass. So it is a **base of anything** in Python. Because `type` is on top of hierarchy of types, `type(type)` returns `type`, i.e. `type` is type of itself.

You also may wonder:

- [What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python)
- [What is a “callable” in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

`type` is a class, that deals with class objects. Invoking it with an object is only one way to use it. You can also use it to create meta classes.

For example

```
>>> MyMetaClass = type("MyMetaClass", (object,), {'foo': 'bar'})
>>> newmeta = MyMetaClass()
>>> newmeta.foo
'bar'
>>> type(MyMetaClass)
<type 'type'>
>>> type(newmeta)
<class '__main__.MyMetaClass'>
```

Comment: Your 'metaclass' isn't actually a metaclass - to be a metaclass, you would have to have `isinstance(newmeta, type)` be True.

Comment: Which means `MyMetaClass` is a class but not a metaclass. For it to be a metaclass, its *instances* would need to be classes, which they're not. It would also need to be a subclass of type, which it isn't.

Comment: @ivc - i see what you are saying now, you are right. +1

Answer (score 0):

You should understand some concepts first:

1. Everything in Python is an object. Every object created in Python is inherited from parent class 'type', its called a Metaclass. Metaclass is parent class of all the object in Python world. So what is the type of 'type' metaclass since everything is an object in Python?
   its 'type' only. 'type' object is of self type.
2. Now 'type()' is a function and 'type' is an object.

> class XYZ:
> pass
> print(type(XYZ))

> output: <class 'type'>