# What else can a django view be made of?

Tags: python, django

I answered an exam that states a Django's view is **not** necessarily a Python's function.

But,in Django's documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/views/) it is stated that a view is simply a Python's function.

What else could a view be made of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be any `callable`. That is e.g. class with `__call__` method implemented. Check django's documentation for [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/).

Also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111255/1048100) to get the idea what is `callable`.