# How does __call__ actually work?

Tags: python, python-internals

Python's magic method `__call__` is called whenever you attempt to call an object. `Cls()()` is thus equal to `Cls.__call__(Cls())`.

Functions are first class objects in Python, meaning they're just callable objects (using `__call__`). However, `__call__` itself is a function, thus it too has `__call__`, which again has its own `__call__`, which again has its own `__call__`.

So `Cls.__call__(Cls())` is thus equal to `Cls.__call__.__call__(Cls())` and again equilevant to `Cls.__call__.__call__.__call__(Cls())` and so on and so forth.

How does this infinite loop end? How does `__call__` actually execute the code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Under the hood, all calls in Python use the same mechanism, and almost all arrive at the same C function in the CPython implementation. Whether an object is an instance of a class with a `__call__` method, a function (itself an object), or a builtin object, all calls (except for optimized special cases) arrive at the function `PyObject_Call`. That C function gets the object's type from the `ob_type` field of the object's `PyObject` struct, and then from the type (another `PyObject` struct) gets the `tp_call` field, which is a function pointer. If `tp_call` is not `NULL`, it calls through *that*, with the args and kwargs structures that were also passed to `PyObject_Call`.

When a class defines a `__call__` method, that sets up the `tp_call` field appropriately.

Here's an article explaining all of this in detail: [Python internals: How callables work](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/03/23/python-internals-how-callables-work/). It even lists and explains the entire `PyObject_Call` function, which isn't very big. If you want to see that function in its native habitat, it's in [Objects/abstract.c](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/abstract.c) in the CPython repo.

Also relevant is this stackoverflow Q&A: [What is a "callable" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python).

Answer (score 5):

There isn't an actual infinite loop, because the `__call__` method is not actually invoked ("called") for all of those situations. It's only invoked directly when there is a function-like call on an object that provides a `__call__` method.

Normal class instantiation `Cls(...)` and regular functional invocation `f()` are known cases that are handled directly. There generally is not an actual invocation of `__call__()`, so there are a finite number of `__call__` method invocations that can ever occur, even in complex cases with deep inheritance, metaclasses, etc.

Because there was some dispute as to whether the short-circuiting of conceptual infinite loops was really happening, let's look at the disassembled bytecode. Consider the following code:

```
def f(x):
    return x + 1

class Adder(object):
    def something(self, x):
        return x + 19
    def __call__(self, x):
        return x + 1

def lotsacalls(y):
    u = f(1)
    a = Adder()
    z = u + a.something(y)
    return a(z * 10)
```

Sorry it's a little complex, as I want to show several instances of short-circuiting--namely, normal `def` functions, `__init__` calls, normal methods, and `__call__` special methods. Now:

[image: annotated disassembly]

So here are a range of times when, if Python were really, truly "walking the tree" of conceptual `__call__` invocations, it would to reference `Function` (and possibly `Method` classes, and invoke their `__call__` methods). It doesn't. It uses the simple bytecode `CALL_FUNCTION` in all cases, short-circuiting the conceptual tree-walk down. *Logically* you can imagine that there is a class `Function` that has a `__call__` method that's invoked when a function (i.e. an instance of the `Function` class) is called. But it doesn't really work that way. The compiler, bytecode interpreter, and other parts of the C-language underpinnings do not *actually* walk meta-class trees. They short-circuit like crazy.

Comment: But functions themselves are just "objects that provide `__call__` method",  including `__call__` itself. Thus to invoke `__call__`, you call its `__call__` which again calls its `__call__`. Where does the line go, and what is it based on?

Comment: No, they're actually not. *Conceptually* they can be viewed as "just objects that provide __call__ method," but actually they are directly understood by the compiler and runtime, and directly implemented. It's just like the Fibonacci Sequence, say. Yes, there is a completely recursive definition, and possible implementation. But most actual implementations are iterative. They short-circuit the logical recursion, so as to not have to laboriously go through long recursion chains.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, because I don't know for sure, but can you prove that? They seem like normal objects to me, and BrianO's answer with links to source code and all seems to support my theory. I'm not saying I'm right and you're wrong, but to me it currently looks like they're just objects and it's the C implementation that calls the `__call__` only once, if one has been defined.

Comment: Sure. I added annotated disassembler output that shows almost all of the cases you imagine as being invocations of `__call__` on some meta-class are in fact not literally present. The compiler and bytecode engine are not deep-walking any class hierarchies or meta-class trees.

Comment: This isn't to say there are *no* situations where more meta-objects get involved (for example, when pure-Python metaclasses are provided, or when there's a deeper inheritance structure). But in all the typical cases, short-circuiting rules the land.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't check any documentation, but from my tests it seem `__call__` isn't always called:

```
def func1(*args, **kargs):
    print "func1 called", args, kargs

def func2(*args, **kargs):
    print "func2 called", args, kargs

func1.__call__ = func2

func1() # here is still called func1

class Cls:
    def __init__(*args, **kargs):
        print "init called", args, kargs
    def __call__(*args, **kargs):
        print "object called", args, kargs

obj = Cls() # here is actually called __init__
obj()  # here is called __call__
```

this prints

```
func1 called () {}
init called (<__main__.Cls instance at 0x0000000002A5ED88>,) {}
object called (<__main__.Cls instance at 0x0000000002A5ED88>,) {}
```

Comment: With `obj = Cls()` notice that `Cls` is just an instance of `type`, so that would be equal to `type.__call__()`. (Google: metaclasses). Although the first finding is interesting, anyone know why `func1.__call__` is not invoked?

Comment: @gre_gor Beautifully empirical demonstration that function calls are special-cased!

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Yes. `func1.__call__` is not invoked because it's a special case. Python does not need to traverse the full concept of "functions are just objects," because this is a very common, well-known situation the complier/runtime can handle more directly. There are **many** instances of such shortcuts in the Python implementation. Python aims for high level semantics, but it often jumps down into special cases and C code for performance.

Comment: Generally speaking, `__special_methods__` don't get called if they're instance variables. They're only called if they're in the class of an object. So, assigning to `func1.__call__` doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks, that makes sense! So functions too are just normal objects and not "special cases" :P