# What happens exactly when one calls a function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What exactly happens when a function is called in Python? Does the interpreter call a `__call__` method of an object? Then, why does the behaviour of function stay the same when I replace its `__call__` method?

(I am working with Python 3)

```python
>>> def foo(): return 1
>>> foo()
1
>>> foo.__call__()
1
>>> foo.__call__ = lambda: 2
>>> foo.__call__()
2
>>> foo()
1
```

Thank you.

Comment: Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34261111/patch-call-of-a-function) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32855927/how-does-call-actually-work).

Comment: Thanks. Questions in your comments really pointed me in a right direction.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Do you, perhaps, know or can you point to why function 'instances' need `__call__` method if `__code__` is what gets executed by an actual call?