# Function call and the __call__ attribute

Tags: python, callable-object

Python's callables are objects that have a `__call__` method.
They are most of the time functions, but might be class instances as well.

But it so happens that functions do have a `__call__` method.
Therefore, a `__call__` method has a `__call__` method as well.
The following REPL session shows that we can chain the `__call__`s:

```
>>> print
<built-in function print>

>>> print.__call__
<method-wrapper '__call__' of builtin_function_or_method object at 0x0000025E2D597F78>

>>> print.__call__.__call__
<method-wrapper '__call__' of method-wrapper object at 0x0000025E2F631438>

>>> print.__call__.__call__.__call__
<method-wrapper '__call__' of method-wrapper object at 0x0000025E2F5F85F8>

>>> print.__call__.__call__.__call__.__call__
<method-wrapper '__call__' of method-wrapper object at 0x0000025E2F725DA0>
```

... and so on.
Remarkably, all these methods have different addresses.
In addition, they all have the same behaviour:

```
>>> print("a")
a
>>> print.__call__("a")
a
>>> print.__call__.__call__("a")
a
>>> print.__call__.__call__.__call__("a")
```

So, when I write `print("a")`, what is actually called?
Is it `print`, or `print.__call__`?
And what if I define a `Foo` class with a `__call__` method?

Furthermore, how is it possible that every `__call__` method has its own *different* `__call__` method?
Could it be that they are in fact created when I tried to access them?

Comment: They have different addresses because they are descriptors, and are bound to the function object instance when accessed.

Comment: [Close enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32855927/846892)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like methods on classes, the `__call__` attribute is a [*descriptor* object](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) defined on the type, bound to the object you looked it up on:

```
>>> type(print).__dict__['__call__']
<slot wrapper '__call__' of 'builtin_function_or_method' objects>
>>> type(print).__dict__['__call__'].__get__(print)
<method-wrapper '__call__' of builtin_function_or_method object at 0x10cc66f78>
>>> print.__call__
<method-wrapper '__call__' of builtin_function_or_method object at 0x10cc66f78>
```

The binding behaviour (through the `__get__` method) is how the resulting `method-wrapper` instance knows to pass in the `print` object as `self`, just like the instance gets passed into methods you defined on a custom Python class.

So yes, that means they are created on demand, and thus will have a unique id. They are otherwise just more instances of the same type.

Answer (score 3):

`print` is an instance of the class `builtin_function_or_method`:

```
>>> type(print)
builtin_function_or_method
```

As we all know (hopefully) when you access a method the instance is implicitly passed as first argument:

```
>>> type(print).__call__(print, 10)
10
>>> print.__call__(10)  # equivalent
10
```

That means you actually have something like a bound method when you access `__call__` of a function. However bound methods (or in this case methodwrappers) are also instances of the type `method_wrapper`:

```
>>> type(print.__call__)
method-wrapper
```

So when you access the `__call__` method of that one it's again a "new" bound method.

```
>>> type(print.__call__).__call__(print.__call__, 10)  # equivalent
10
```

At this point it becomes recursive because a method of a method-wrapper is just another method-wrapper instance:

```
>>> type(print.__call__.__call__)
method-wrapper
```

However all that does it just creates a lot of "unnecessary" bound methods...