# Trigering post_save signal only after transaction has completed

Tags: django, api, django-models, transactions, django-signals

I have written some APIs, for which the respective functions executive inside a transaction block. I am calling the `save()` method (after some modifications) on instance/s of a/several Model/s, and also consecutively indexing some JSON related information of the instance/s in **Elasticsearch**. I want the database to rollback even if for some reason the `save()` for one of the instances or indexing to the **Elasticsearch** fails.

Now, the problem is arising that even inside the transaction block, the `post_save()` signals gets called, and that is an issue because some notifications are being triggered from those signals.

Is there a way to trigger `post_save()` signals only after the transactions have completed successful?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not really. The signals have nothing to do with the db transaction success or failure, but with the save method itself - before the call you have the pre_save signal fired and after the call you have the post_save signal fired.

There are 2 approaches here:

- you are going to inspect the instance in the post_save method and decide that the model was saved successfully or not; simplest way to do that: in the save method, after the transaction executed successfully, annotate your instance with a flag, say `instance.saved_successfully = True`, which you will test in the post_save handler.
- you are going to ditch the post_save signal and create a custom signal for yourself, which you will trigger after the transaction ran successfully.

Makes sense?

P.S.

If you strictly need to bind to the transaction commit signal, have a look over this package: https://django-transaction-hooks.readthedocs.org/en/latest/; it looks like the functionality is integrated in Django 1.9a.

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried the first approach, I was setting `instance.in_transaction = True`, but that did create a lot of the confusion as many of the other developers then missed the handling in their signals. I think, the second approach will be much more easy to handle, and will be with least complications.

Comment: Signals are included in transaction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36331753/are-django-signals-also-included-inside-of-the-transaction-atomic-decorator

Answer (score 47):

I think the simplest way is to use [transaction.on_commit()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.on_commit). Here's an example using the models.Model subclass `Photo` that will only talk to Elasticsearch once the current transaction is over:

```
from django.db import transaction
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=Photo)
def save_photo(**kwargs):
    transaction.on_commit(lambda: talk_to_elasticsearch(kwargs['instance']))
```

Note that if the `transaction.on_commit()` gets executed while not in an active transaction, it will run right away.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. However, I was wondering how you were able to test the signal using django's test api. Test cases are wrapped in transactions that are always rolled back, resulting in the signal function never executing and the tests failing.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr If you use Django's unittest based framework, you can use [TransactionTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase), and if you use pytest, you can use the [transactional_db fixture](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#transactional-db) found in the [pytest-django package](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django)!

Comment: why do you use lambda?

Comment: @JuanDiegoRamirez We need to pass a function that takes no arguments into `transaction.on_commit`, so this was just the most concise way to express that. We could also just define a separate inline function like `def _func(): talk_to_elasticsearch(kwargs['instance'])` and use it like `transaction.on_commit(_func)`

Answer (score 7):

I was having serious issues with django's admin not allowing post_save transactions on parent objects when they had inline children being modified.

This was my solution to an error complaining about conducting queries in the middle of an atomic block:

```
def on_user_post_save_impl(user):
     do_something_to_the_user(user)

def on_user_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if not transaction.get_connection().in_atomic_block:
        on_user_post_save_impl(instance)
    else:
        transaction.on_commit(lambda: on_user_post_save_impl(instance))
```

Comment: This does not work - 
`AttributeError: "'module' object has no attribute 'on_commit'"`

Comment: Have you imported transaction from django? I think it is django.db.transaction

Comment: why do you use lambda?

Comment: @JuanDiegoRamirez probably because I had a lambda at some point instead of a name function, and just never removed the lambda. It works.

Answer (score 1):

We are using this little nugget:

```
def atomic_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if hasattr(instance, "atomic_post_save") and transaction.get_connection().in_atomic_block:
        transaction.on_commit(lambda: instance.atomic_post_save(sender, instance=instance, **kwargs))

post_save.connect(atomic_post_save)
```

Then we simply define a `atomic_post_save` method on any model we like:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    def atomic_post_save(self, sender, created, **kwargs):
        talk_to_elasticsearch(self)
```

Two things to notice:

1. We only call `atomic_post_save` when inside a transaction.
2. It's too late in the flow to send messages and have them included in the current request from inside `atomic_post_save`.

Comment: why do you use lambda?

Comment: The lamda not is necesary https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/transactions/#s-performing-actions-after-commit  , i didn't vote negative  on the contrary i will vote positive, take care bro

Comment: @JuanDiegoRamirez it truly is, read the docs you linked :)

Comment: In the text says: "You can also wrap your function in a lambda", is optional, with function also it works, def do_something(): pass transaction.on_commit(do_something)

Comment: @JuanDiegoRamirez first argument to on_commit must be a callable, i.e. something that can be invoked inside `on_commit`. So either a reference to a function, a lambda or even a class instance that implements a `__call__` method. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable

Comment: I ask you, is it strictly necessary to use lambda in on_commit? yes or no?