# If database autocommit mode is enabled, why should I care about transaction.on_commit()?

Tags: mysql, django, transactions

I've read that Django > 1.9 introduces `transaction.on_commit` in order to avoid race conditions. I know that Django sets database autocommit to true by default, so each query becomes a transaction at db level.

However, take this example,

```
from django.db import transaction

def some_view(request):
    obj = SomeModel.objects.create(field=value)
    transaction.on_commit(lambda: some_async_task(obj.pk))
```

Why should I wrap `some_async_task(obj.pk)` inside `transaction.on_commit`? I'm not sure how transactions work behind the scenes. All this time I've been thinking that as autocommit is enabled, `create` or `save` method should be a transaction itself, and then, in the next statement that object should exist in database.

Comment: Not all project use default autocommit. And some views can be decorated to be run in transaction / manually managed.

Comment: Also according to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.on_commit), `If you call on_commit() while there isn’t an active transaction, the callback will be executed immediately.`. So there's no harm to use `transaction.on_commit`.

Comment: For example, it happened to me that inside a post_save I triggered a task sending instance pk. Then inside the task tried to retrieve the instance by its pk and failed because the transaction hadn't been commited yet. If it's autocommit enabled, why isn't the object commited into db just after save()?

Comment: Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33192224/2225682

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I've found the issue. I actually haven't explained the whole thing. Autocommit mode works right. It commits instantly, except when there's an active transaction.

I've realized I only expirienced this in **Django's admin**. The add/change views are wrapped inside a transaction. SO, my code inside `post_save` signal was triggered inside and the admin's save transaction wasn't finished yet.

That's why it makes sense to use `transaction.on_commit` anyway (added in Django > 1.9), because in this case its argument function would be triggered after outer transaction ends.

I'm using [Django 1.6.5](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6.5/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1187) but this also happens in [1.11](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1407)

Hope this helps someone else.