# What really makes an object callable in python

Tags: python

I am trying to optimize the performance of an object and switched from this pattern:

```
class match(object):
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.matchfn = fn
    def __call__(self, val):
        return self.matchfn(val)
```

to

```
class match(object):
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.__call__ = fn
```

It is particularly important as `__call__` is called hundreds of thousands of time on this object. 
From testing in a shell, it seems to work and be much faster but once integrated with all the rest of my code it does not work.

For an obscure reason my instance has a `__call__` method but isn't considered callable.

Here is a pdb session I used to try to debug the issue:

```
 844         def __call__(self, value):
 845             for match in self._matchers:
 846                 import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
 847  ->             if match(value):
 848                     return True
 849             return False

(Pdb++) print match.__call__
<function <lambda> at 0x1258b0a28>
(Pdb++) print match.__call__(value)
False
(Pdb++) print match(value)
*** TypeError: 'match' object is not callable
```

What could I be missing?

Comment: The error mentions a `match` object rather than a `matcher` object. What type of objects does `self._matchers` contain?

Comment: The example I put is just informative, fixing it. `self._matchers` contains `match` objects have described above.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: related: [What is a “callable” in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/111234/4279)

Comment: You're using the name "match" in too many places.  It's the name of a class, it's the index variable in the for loop, and it's a function call in `if match(value)`.  Can you figure out how the interpreter will handle this mess?  What will pdb do?  I don't want to think about it.  Rename something and try your program again.