# How does one initialize a variable with tf.get_variable and a numpy value in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I wanted to initialize some of the variable on my network with numpy values. For the sake of the example consider:

```
init=np.random.rand(1,2)
tf.get_variable('var_name',initializer=init)
```

when I do that I get an error:

```
ValueError: Shape of a new variable (var_name) must be fully defined, but instead was <unknown>.
```

why is it that I am getting that error?

To try to fix it I tried doing:

```
tf.get_variable('var_name',initializer=init, shape=[1,2])
```

which yielded a even weirder error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

I tried reading [the docs and examples](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#variable_scope) but it didn't really help.

Is it not possible to initialize variables with numpy arrays with the get_variable method in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 42):

The following works, if you convert the constant NumPy array into a constant `Tensor`:

```
init = tf.constant(np.random.rand(1, 2))
tf.get_variable('var_name', initializer=init)
```

The documentation for `get_variable` is a little lacking indeed. Just for your reference, the `initializer` argument has to be either a TensorFlow `Tensor` object (which can be constructed by calling `tf.constant` on a `numpy` value in your case), or a 'callable' that takes two arguments, `shape` and `dtype`, the shape and data type of the value that it's supposed to return. Again, in your case, you can write the following in case you wanted to use the 'callable' mechanism:

```
init = lambda shape, dtype: np.random.rand(*shape)
tf.get_variable('var_name', initializer=init, shape=[1, 2])
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python) is a great answer to your question.

Comment: A `callable` is a function or something that can be called like a function.

Comment: `tf.get_variable('var_name', initializer=np.random.rand(1, 2))` seems to work now on r0.10.

Comment: It seems now this has slightly changed such that the `lambda` takes an additional input called `partition_info`, so I had to modify the definition to be `init = lambda shape, dtype, partition_info: np.random.rand(*shape)`.

Answer (score 10):

@keveman Answered well, and for supplement, there is the usage of  **tf.get_variable('var_name', initializer=init)**, the tensorflow document did give a comprehensive example.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

value = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
# value = np.array(value)
# value = value.reshape([2, 4])
init = tf.constant_initializer(value)

print('fitting shape:')
tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Session() :
    x = tf.get_variable('x', shape = [2, 4], initializer = init)
    x.initializer.run()
    print(x.eval())

    fitting shape :
[[0.  1.  2.  3.]
[4.  5.  6.  7.]]

print('larger shape:')
tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Session() :
    x = tf.get_variable('x', shape = [3, 4], initializer = init)
    x.initializer.run()
    print(x.eval())

    larger shape :
[[0.  1.  2.  3.]
[4.  5.  6.  7.]
[7.  7.  7.  7.]]

print('smaller shape:')
tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Session() :
    x = tf.get_variable('x', shape = [2, 3], initializer = init)

    * <b>`ValueError`< / b > : Too many elements provided.Needed at most 6, but received 8
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant_initializer

Answer (score 4):

If the variable was already created (ie from some complex function), just use `load`.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#load

```
x_var = tf.Variable(tf.zeros((1, 2), tf.float32))
x_val = np.random.rand(1,2).astype(np.float32)

sess = tf.Session()
x_var.load(x_val, session=sess)

# test
assert np.all(sess.run(x_var) == x_val)
```