# Python syntax: x = SomeClass(some_input)(x)

Tags: python, syntax

I am trying to understand the following python snippet:

```
 x = SomeObject
 x = SomeClass(some_input)(x)
```

Can anyone shed some light on what is going on here?

Comment: `SomeClass` is apparently callable, so when you create an instance – `y = SomeClass(some_input)` – you can call it: `y(…)`.

Comment: Can you provide the definitions for `SomeObject` and `SomeClass`?

Comment: The class definition is a bit too involved to post it here. But thanks for pointing me to the direction of "callable classes", I obviously need to look into that concept to understand this syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending others response will try to give you a more general answer, on how Python will solve that statement

```
x = SomeClass(some_input)(x)
```

First Python's interpreter will try solve the statement after the `=` and then assign it to `x`, so this leave us with_

```
SomeClass(some_input)(x)
```

In this statement there are two main elements the `SomeClass` instation and the `call` for the result instance that should be a callable)

```
SomeClass(some_input):  (x)
#---instantiation----:--call--
```

It will solve first the left-side to determine what should be *called*, in the left-side We have a Class instantiation, it means that Python interpreter will call the `SomeClass.__init__(...)` method with the arguments (`some_input`).  This involves that if `some_input` is a call of a method, instantiation, formula or so itself, it will try to solve that first.

```
SomeClass(some_input) # => <new object>
```

This `<new_object>` is the one who will be *called* with the arguments (`x`) and this is possible because the `SomeClass` can (and should in this example) be *callable* just with implementing the `__call__` method as you would do with `__init__`, as example:

```
class Add:
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
        print "Sum of", self.num1,"and",self.num2, "is:"

    def __call__(self):
        return (self.num1 + self.num2)

add = Add(1,2)
print add()
```

+[More info about objects being callables](https://technobeans.wordpress.com/2011/01/31/python-making-objects-callable/)

***note**: The reference `<new_object>`, as it not bound with any variable, will be lost after the last statement.*

Answer (score 3):

It can be simplified to the following (assuming that the auxiliary variables `y` and `z` are not used by surrounding code):

```
y = SomeObject
z = SomeClass(some_input)
x = z(y)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  But what is happening here:

   x = z(y)  ?

Looks like a function call, but z is an object of SomeClass and not a function...

Comment: In the expression `z(y)` `z` must be a [callable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python) object (functions are just one example of callable objects).