# defaultdict : first argument must be callable or None

Tags: python, defaultdict

I ran the following code :

```
from collections import defaultdict
lst = list(range(0,5))
d = defaultdict(lst)
```

and I got this error :

```
TypeError: first argument must be callable or None
```

Please help

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For a `defaultdict` the **default value** is usually **not really a value**, it a **factory**: a method that generates a new value. You can solve this issue by using a *lambda expression* that generates a list:

```
lst = lambda:list(range(0,5))
d = defaultdict(lst)
```

This is also a good idea here, since otherwise **all default values** would **reference the same list**. For instance here:

```
d[1].append(14)
```

will **not** have impact on `d[2]` (given both `d[1]` and `d[2]` did not exist).

You **can however achieve this** with:

```
val = list(range(0,5))
lst = lambda:val
d = defaultdict(lst)
```

But this can have unwanted side effects: if you here perform `d[1].append(14)` then `d[2]` will be `[1,2,3,4,5,14]` and `d[1] is d[2]` will be `True`:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> val = list(range(0,5))
>>> lst = lambda:val
>>> d = defaultdict(lst)
>>> d[1]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> d[1].append(14)
>>> d[2]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 14]
>>> d[1] is d[2]
True
```

whereas:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> lst = lambda:list(range(0,5))
>>> d = defaultdict(lst)
>>> d[1]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> d[1].append(14)
>>> d[2]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> d[1] is d[2]
False
```

Comment: nicely explained.

Comment: So I can't use a defaultdict on an existing list, say `a = [5,2,3]` ?

Comment: @Arcyno: not as far as I know. Note that furthermore in that case **all** default values would reference **the same list**.

Answer (score 9):

You should make the parameter a callable, say, using `lambda`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: list(range(0,5)))
print(d[0])
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 6):

[**Default dictionary**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) accepts callable as first argument(which is default factory for not defined values), so what you want to do is the next step:

```
from collections import defaultdict


default_factory = (lambda: list(range(0,5))
d = defaultdict(default_factory)
```

See more about callable in [What is a "callable" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python) SO question.