# Can't use collections.defaultdict() in google-app-engine

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python, defaultdict

Trying to use collections.defaultdict() to create an histogram in google-app-engine :

```
class myDS(ndb.Model):

    values = ndb.PickleProperty()
    hist = ndb.PickleProperty()

class Handler:
    my_ds = myDS()
    my_ds.values = {}   
    my_ds.hist = defaultdict(lambda : 0)
```

And got the error (from log)

```
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/277b61042b697c7a_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1331, in call
    newvalue = method(self, value)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/277b61042b697c7a_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 1862, in _to_base_type
    return pickle.dumps(value, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

Any way to solve this?

Comment: Note that `ndb` is only supported in the standard GAE environment, which only works with python 2.7. Donno if that's related to your problem or not.

Comment: @DanCornilescu defaultdict should be included in python2.7.. https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: @snakecharmerb How can I access the logs? I didn't know there are logs :)

Comment: To view cloud logs, see [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs).  The dev server also produces logs, which may be written to the terminal (the default) or file.  See also docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/logs/)

Comment: @snakecharmerb Amazing , had no idea I can see the log! I edited the post with the log error

Comment: I don't think you can pickle a function, so putting that lambda inside the `defaultdict` might be what is causing the problem.

Comment: @CarlSmith this is the only way I know to init a defaultdict - is there any other wat I can use it here?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. You can just call `defaultdict` with no args to initialise it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't actually know how `defaultdict` works, so ignore me if I'm being ignorant. I was really just mentioning that you cannot pickle a function, in case that helped.

Comment: @CarlSmith this is the way I know to init defaultdict - if there is another way I will use it..

Comment: @snakecharmerb No , I get a error TypeError: first argument must be callable

Comment: @snakecharmerb yep.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137849/defaultdict-first-argument-must-be-callable-or-none

Comment: @snakecharmerb you meant the word "int"? I thought you meant <int> (to put a number there). How does python "knows" to put 0 when I write "int"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PickleProperty field require a value that is serializable using Python's pickle protocol (see [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference) for more info):

> PickleProperty:   Value is a Python object (such as a list or a dict or a
>   string) that is serializable using Python's pickle protocol; Cloud
>   Datastore stores the pickle serialization as a blob. Unindexed by
>   default. Optional keyword argument: compressed.

See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16439531/2190251) from Martijn Pieters:

> Pickle cannot handle lambdas; pickle only ever handles data, not code,
>   and lambdas contain code. Functions can be pickled, but just like
>   class definitions only if the function can be imported. A function
>   defined at the module level can be imported. Pickle just stores a
>   string in that case, the full 'path' of the function to be imported
>   and referenced when unpickling again.

There are multiple options to work with default values, depending on your use case.