# Make Python module callable

Tags: python-2.7, module, callable

need some help making the below a callable object for another script e.g `scrape.run()`

I'm not sure where to start any pointers?

scrape.py

```
from clint.textui import puts, colored
import subprocess, sys
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep as sleep
today = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
multimon_ng = subprocess.Popen("rtl_fm -A lut -s 22050  -f 148.81250M | multimon-ng -t raw -a FLEX -f alpha /dev/stdin", 
 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
 stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
 shell=True) 
while True: 
 try:
  nextline = multimon_ng.stdout.readline() 
  if not nextline: 
   pass 
  else: 
   try: 
    flex, mdate, mtime, bitrate, other, capcode, o2, msg = nextline.split(" ", 7) 
   except ValueError: 
    print "invalid line", nextline 
   else: 
    puts(colored.yellow(capcode), newline=False)
    puts(" [", newline=False)
    puts(colored.green(mdate + " " + str(datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M'))), newline=False)
    puts(" ]", newline=False)
    puts(msg)
 except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "exit"
 multimon_ng.poll()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a "callable" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the bottom of the script.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    function_you_wish_to_call_here()
```

Anything under the if statement will run when you call the script directly.