# Matrices depending on a parameter in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix

I've got a matrix which can be defined using a parameter, so this is like for a parameter 'a' I can label my Matrix as A(a) where the entries depend on this 'a', the thing is that I'd like to create a set of this matrices using a domain for this 'a's. So my question is, How do I define the set of 'a' in order to obtain the set of matrices?

Comment: Hi, I've got a set of values for 'a' (real values in general), and each entry in this matrix is a function of this parameter, I'd like to generate a set of this matrices for each value of a.

Comment: You have been happy of obtaining answers on SO? Consider reading [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Something you can do is using the method [`fromfunction`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html) of the [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) library. Then with a (nxn) square matrix it would be as simple as

```
import numpy as np

def your_function(row_index, col_index, a):
    # ... do stuff and compute your result
    return result

n = 2
a = np.pi
your_matrix = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: your_function(i, j, a), (n, n), dtype=np.float)
```

and if you want it to be in a [callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python) form, actually as you asked, you can do

```
A = lambda a : np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: your_function(i, j, a), (n, n), dtype=np.float)
```

Or if you do not want to use an [anonymous function](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk)

```
def A(a):
    return  np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: your_function(i, j, a), (n, n), dtype=np.float)
```

---

Let do a simple example

```
def your_function(row_index, col_index, a):
    return row_index + col_index + a
n = 2
A = lambda a : np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: your_function(i, j, a), (n, n), dtype=np.float)
```

Use case

```
>>> A(1)
array([[ 1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  3.]])

>>> A(np.pi)
array([[ 3.1415926535897931,  4.1415926535897931],
       [ 4.1415926535897931,  5.1415926535897931]])
```

Comment: If I answered your question, the way this site works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)