# "__call__" equivalent in Matlab classdef

Tags: python, matlab, class, object, call

Is it possible to define a class method in MATLAB similar to the "**call**" method in Python?

How would you implement the following Python class in MATLAB.

```
class Basic(object):

    def __init__(self, basic):
        self.basic = basic

    def __call__(self, x, y):
        return (numpy.sin(y) *numpy.cos(x))

    def _calc(self, y, z):
        x = numpy.linspace(0, numpy.pi/2, 90)
        basic = self(x, y)
        return x[tuple(basic< b).index(False)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a class object in MATLAB that is ["callable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python), you would need to modify the [`subsref`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html) method. This is the method that is called when you use subscripted indexing operations like `A(i)`, `A{i}`, or `A.i` for object `A`. Since calling a function and indexing an object both use `()` in MATLAB, you would have to modify this method to mimic callable behavior. Specifically, you would likely want to define `()` indexing to exhibit callable behavior for a [*scalar* obect](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/empty-matrices-scalars-and-vectors.html), but exhibit the normal vector/matrix indexing for non-scalar objects.

Here's a sample [class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/user-defined-classes.html) (using [this documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/code-patterns-for-subsref-and-subsasgn-methods.html) for defining `subsref` methods) which raises its property to a power for its callable behavior:

```matlab
classdef Callable

  properties
    Prop
  end

  methods

    % Constructor
    function obj = Callable(val)
      if nargin > 0
        obj.Prop = val;
      end
    end

    % Subsref method, modified to make scalar objects callable
    function varargout = subsref(obj, s)
      if strcmp(s(1).type, '()')
        if (numel(obj) == 1)
          % "__call__" equivalent: raise stored value to power of input
          varargout = {obj.Prop.^s(1).subs{1}};
        else
          % Use built-in subscripted reference for vectors/matrices
          varargout = {builtin('subsref', obj, s)};
        end
      else
        error('Not a valid indexing expression');
      end
    end

  end

end
```

And here are some usage examples:

```matlab
>> C = Callable(2)  % Initialize a scalar Callable object

C = 
  Callable with properties:
    Prop: 2

>> val = C(3)  % Invoke callable behavior

val =
     8         % 2^3

>> Cvec = [Callable(1) Callable(2) Callable(3)]  % Initialize a Callable vector

Cvec = 
  1×3 Callable array with properties:
    Prop

>> C = Cvec(3)  % Index the vector, returning a scalar object

C = 
  Callable with properties:
    Prop: 3

>> val = C(4)  % Invoke callable behavior

val =
    81         % 3^4
```