# python hasattr() to differentiate a method and an attribute

Tags: python, oop

As some good people showed me that `callable()` can be used to solve this problem, I still found it to be a different question, because anyone that has this question in mind will not found the answer because he won't connect this directly to `callable()`. Plus I found a possible way to go around without using `callable()`, which is to use `type()` as showed in one of the answers from myself.

Assume I create a simple class as `Cls`

```
class Cls():
    attr1 = 'attr1'

    def __init__(self, attr2):
        self.attr2 = attr2

    def meth1(self, num):
        return num**2

obj = Cls('attribute2')
print(hasattr(obj, 'attr1'))  # >>> True
print(hasattr(obj, 'attr2'))  # >>> True
print(hasattr(obj, 'meth1'))  # >>> True
```

From what I learned, an attribute is a variable inside a class, and a method is a function inside a class. They are not the same.

Apparently, there is no `hasmethod()` to be called by python. And it seems that `hasattr()` really gives all `True` to my test on `'attr1'`, `'attr2'`, `'meth1'`. It does not differentiate from an attribute or a method.

And if I use `dir()`, the attributes and methods will all show up in the output, and you can't really tell which one is what type either.

Can someone please explain me why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a "callable" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python)

Comment: In the Custom classes and Class instances *sections* of  [The Standard Type Hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) , methods and functions are referred to as class attributes also.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No matter it's a variable or a method, they are all considered "attributes". So `hasattr` returns `True`.

The way in which methods are different is that they are callable. This can be checked by calling `callable`. So if you want to figure out whether an attribute is callable, you can

```
if hasattr(obj, "attr1"):
    if callable(obj.attr1):
        # attr1 is a method!
    else:
         # attr1 is not a method but an attribute
else:
    # attr1 is not an attribute
```

Comment: thanks, did not realize that callable() can solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

You can define `hasmethod()` as below

```
def hasmethod(obj,method_name):
     return hasattr(obj,method_name) and callable(getattr(obj,method_name))

print(hasmethod(obj,'meth1')) #True
print(hasmethod(obj,'attr1')) #False
```

Comment: quite Interesting

Answer (score 0):

Something interesting that I found is that if I call `type()` on the attributes, a method will shows up as a method, while attributes will be a string or an int or any other types.

```
print(type(obj.attr1))  # >>> <class 'str'>
print(type(obj.attr2))  # >>> <class 'str'>
print(type(obj.meth1))  # >>> <class 'method'>
```

maybe this can tell whether it is a method or not?