# What is a callable in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I thought a callable is just a function from the tf-library that I *call*. This:

```
tensor = tf.while_loop(tf.less(tf.rank(tensor), ndims),        # cond
                       tf.append(tensor, axis=axis),           # body
                       loop_vars = [tensor])                   # loop_vars
```

errors to `TypeError: cond must be callable.`

What is a callable condition if not `tf.less()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A callable is anything that can be called. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python).

The cond should be a function. You can use `lambda` ([See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful)) to make your condition `callable`.

[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) there is a minimal example of how to use `tf.while_loop`:

```
i = tf.constant(0)
c = lambda i: tf.less(i, 10)
b = lambda i: tf.add(i, 1)
r = tf.while_loop(c, b, [i])
```

And in the end, not a bad idea to post a minimal code that actually runs and generates your error.

Answer (score 1):

`tf.less` is an `Operation` object. To make it callable, just use a `lambda`:

```
tensor = tf.while_loop(lambda tensor: tf.less(tf.rank(tensor), ndims), # cond
                       lambda tensor: tf.append(tensor, axis=axis),    # body
                       loop_vars = [tensor])                           # loop_vars
```