# Setting boto3 dynamodb endpoint_url globaly

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I want to use [dynamodb local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html) for local (unit) testing of my python/boto3 based application.

Now I can do something like this

```
if test_mode:
    client = boto3.client("dynamodb", endpoint_url="localhost:8000")
    resource = boto3.resource("dynamodb", endpoint_url="localhost:8000")
else:
    client = boto3.client("dynamodb")
    resource = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
```

But I would like to avoid the `test_mode` check.

Can I somehow "prepare" boto3 so the dynamodb endpoint URL is set globally?

**Update**

To further explain what I want. I want some sort of function, where I can say:

```
boto3.setGlobalDynamodbEndpoint("http://localhost:8000")
```

such that when, after calling this function, I do:

```
client = boto3.client("dynamodb")
resource = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
```

The endpoint will automatically be set to `"http://localhost:8000"`

Comment: What do you mean by `prepare` and `globally`?

Comment: @helloV I updated my question, trying to further explain what I mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no built-in function in the `boto3` library that will do this for you, but you could achieve a similar result using the [`functools.partial` utility](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) in the Python standard library. This tool takes a [Python callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python) and one or more arguments, and returns a new callable that does the same thing, but with those arguments "pre-set". In functional programming jargon, this is called ["partially applying"](https://www.grokacademy.com/lessons/demystifying-currying-and-partial-function-application/) a function (hence the name `partial`).

For example,

```
import functools
import boto3

URL = "http://localhost:8000"
boto3.client = functools.partial(botot3.client, endpoint_url=URL)
boto3.resource = functools.partial(boto3.resource, endpoint_url=URL)
```

By redefining `boto3.client` and `boto3.resource` to be our new partial, instead of the original versions from the library, we're [monkey-patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching) `boto3`.

Later on in your code, when you call:

```
client = boto3.client("dynamodb")
resource = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
```

You won't need to explicitly pass `endpoint_url` because the client and resource objects will be automatically instantiated with the previously-set URL value in the `partial` object.

Answer (score 2):

I've just submitted a PR to the boto3 project to use an env var to override the endpoint_url, which might be useful for this.

https://github.com/boto/boto3/pull/2746

https://github.com/rwillmer/boto3