# Why do I get different results?

Tags: django, django-file-upload

I use Django 2.x.
I try to upload the file **"image.png"**.

**models.py:**

```
def file_name(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('uploads', 'my_name.png')

class FileForm(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=file_name, null=True)
```

As a result **image.png** is uploads into "uploads" folder with new filename "my_name.png" (..uploads/my_name.png)

But when I do this: (I just take *os.path.join('uploads', 'my_name.png')* and put instead *file_name*)

```
class FileForm(models.Model):
        file = models.FileField(upload_to=os.path.join('uploads', 'my_name.png'), null=True)
```

The result is **image.png** is just uploaded into "uploads/my_name.png" folder (...uploads/my_name.png/image.png)

Why is this happening?

Comment: Because you need a callable. What you have done in the first one is right, except you need to use `filename` instead of `'my_name.png'`.

Comment: Thank you. I specially wrote "my_name.png"  to find out how it works. What do you mean "callable", sorry I'm new here. I thought I can put result of this function into FileField and result will be the same

Comment: @Valery You can check what is callable in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/111255/4436641).  `upload_to` expects a string of the directory, if you use a callable in the upload_to, it will be the absolute file path including the filename.  So in your case, `upload_to=os.path.join('uploads', 'my_name.png')` will set the upload directory to `uploads/my_name.png/`.  You can see it more in this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).

Comment: @Rieljun Liguid Oh thank you so much! I completely understand this.
Also I find the the condition in **file.py**:
    `def generate_filename(self, instance, filename):

        if callable(self.upload_to):

            filename = self.upload_to(instance, filename)`