# Is it possible to make a instance of a class callable

Tags: python, class, oop

I want to call a instance of a class directly,

for expample-

```
class A(Object):
    def __init(self,temp):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.val = temp

    def get_val(self):
        return self.val
```

Now, creating an instance -

```
my_var = A('something')
print(my_var.get_val())
```

but i want to print the value only by using -

```
print(my_var) or print(my_var())
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a "callable" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python)

Comment: Take a look at the `__str__()` and `__repr__()` magic functions of a class.

Comment: Related reading: [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__), [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `__str__()` method. When you are printing an object reference directly, it internally calls `obj.__str__()`. Hence, you can achieve what you want by overriding the said method.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,temp):
        self.val = temp

    def get_val(self):
        return self.val


    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_val()


my_var = A('something')
print my_var
```

OUTPUT:

```
something
```

Comment: Awesome,Thanks Bro !!