# Rolling the dices game, TypeError: 'str' object is not callable error

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I wrote a little game in Python 3, and I want to repeat the dice rolling if the input is not 'stop'. If I write stop it is going to stop the program, so this is working, but when I write something else it is not repeating.
Here is the source code:

```
print('Throw the dices, then type stop if you want to stop')
from random import *
while input != 'stop':
    random1 = randint(1, 6)
    random2 = randint(1, 6)
    print('The numbers are: ',  random1,' ', random2)
    input = input()
```

Comment: `input = input()` - this seems like a bad idea if you also want to call that function again later...

Comment: ^ Yeah you are overloading the method `input` so it is trying to do `<string_input>()`

Comment: you could change your `while` loop to `while input()!='stop':` and remove the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's probably a couple things that are confusing you (and other new Python users). This answer will attempt to clarify precisely why you're seeing the error you're seeing at the risk of sounding pedantic.

**1) What does it mean to be callable?**

Callables are objects that can be called by placing `()` at the end of said object (well sort of, some callables take arguments, but for now we'll pretend that they don't). For example, the builtin function `input` is a callable. You can do `input()`, for instance, like your program does. You can read more detail about the subject here: [What is a "callable" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python)

**2) First class functions**

Unlike other langauges you might be used to (like Java), Python has first class functions. This means that you can assign values to functions, and pass them around like objects. This is very powerful for programming. However, it also means that you can blast over a built-in function, like `input`, and instead assign `input` to a string. This is what your program does.

**3) Strings can't be called**

A string is a datatype which is not a callable. What would it mean to call or execute a string? So if you have `x = "my_super_string"`, `x()` doesn't make any sense. Thus, if you do this, the Python interpreter will give you a `TypeError` saying that strings can't be called.

Here's a minimal example of what's happening in your code and why you get the `TypeError`:

```
>>> input
<built-in function input>
>>> input = input()
"some string."
>>> input
'some string.'
>>> input()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Note how the name `input` changed from a `<built-in function input>` to the string `'some_string.'`.

Answer (score 2):

Your error arises from the fact you are overwriting `input`. On the second iteration, `input` is no longer a function but a string. Use some other name such as `user_input`.

It is a common mistake to use names such as `sum`, `input`, `max` for variables. Those should be avoided since they overwrite [builtin functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

Although, let me point out that iterating inputs until a given value is entered can be done with [`iter` second form](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter).

```
from random import randint

print('Throw the dices, then type stop if you want to stop')

for _ in iter(input, 'stop'):
    print('The numbers are: ', randint(1, 6), randint(1, 6))
```

As sidenotes, try to avoid using `import *` and keep imports at the top of your script.

Answer (score 0):

You use both 'input' as variable name and as a [function call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input). 
While the input-variable is being called first Python interprets it's like a str-type variable. Try changing that name to, ie. inp and see how it will behave.

Edit: you also have to define that inp as ie. "" before the loop starts.