# print(x) TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random 
print("guass a number in between 0 t0 10")
x=random.randint(0,10)
print(x)
while True:
    print=("if i have to think lower press 1,if i have to think higher press 2,if correct press 3")
    y=int(input("press your choice"))
    if y==1:
        x=random.randint(0,x)
        print(x)
    elif y==2:
        x=random .randint(x,10)
        print(x)
    elif y==3:
        print("thank you")
    else:
        print("chosee a valid no")
        break
```

can any 1 help me in it......

Comment: Please format the code properly!

Answer (score 1):

In the first iteration of your `while-loop` you initialize a variable named `print` with the value `"if i have to think lower press 1,if i have to think higher press 2,if correct press 3"`

I don't think you meant to do this.

```
print=("if i have to think lower press 1,if i have to think higher press 2,if correct press 3")
```

When you do this and try to call the `print` function, instead of it doing what you expect it to, it refers to the a string. Since a string is not a [callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python) it throws an error.

This is a common error for new programmers run into called [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)
Instead try,

```
print("if i have to think lower press 1,if i have to think higher press 2,if correct press 3")
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of why you occured

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

is print=("if i have to think lower press 1, if i have to think higher press 2,if correct press 3")`.

You call `print` again, from then on `print` is a `str` instead of a function.

Change:

```
print=("if i have to think lower press 1,if i have to think higher press 2,if correct press 3")
```

to

```
print ("if i have to think lower press 1,if i have to think higher press 2,if correct press 3")
```