# What is the difference between int and int() in Python

Tags: python, input

I'm just trying to understand what is the difference between int and int().
Here is my code:

```
def function(define):
    if type(define) == int:
        return 'sorry'
    else:
        return len(define)

print(function(10))
```

and it returns: sorry

```
File "exercise2.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(function(10))
  File "exercise2.py", line 12, in function
    return len(define)
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Comment: While it's important to know the difference, you can't call `len` on either of those things.

Comment: It doesn't return sorry, it raises a TypeError on the other line.... have you read the error message at all?

Comment: Also, it sounds like you may have reassigned `int`.

Answer (score 3):

[int](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex) - a numeric **type**

[int()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) - a **method** that return an integer object from any number or string

both are not **sequences/collections** so they do not have length thus you can't use [len()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) on them.

A better way to check if the variable is an int is:

```
def function(define):
    if isinstance(define, int):
        return 'sorry'
    else:
        return len(define)

print(function(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, technically `int` is a class but you can also think of it as a data type as others have noted. Since it is a [callable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python) `int()` would invoke the `__call__` method for the `int` class. For the sake of this question, you can think of it as a constructor that takes a string representation of an integer and returns an int.

Here's an example in the Python REPL for clarity.

```
Python 3.7.0 (default, Sep 22 2018, 18:29:00)
[Clang 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> int
<class 'int'>
>>> int('1')
1
>>> int('a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
>>> int.__call__('1')
1
>>> isinstance(int('1'), int)
True
>>> type(1) is int
True
```

Answer (score 0):

int is used to do things like determine the type of a variable (as you've done in your example).  int() is used to convert a non-int variable to an int (i.e. "45" becomes 45).  I'm not really sure what you're getting at with your example.  Everything seems to be running correctly and then you just pasted the errors without any kind of explanation.

Comment: thank you so much. really simple and helpful explanation