# Why is calling register() required for tkinter input validation?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
def check_the_input_only_allows_digits_only(inp):
    # A function for validating the input, the purpose of this is to let
    # the user enter only digits.
    if inp.isdigit() or inp is "" or inp == "\b" or inp is None:
        return True
    else:
        return False


reg = creditor.register(check_the_input_only_allows_digits_only)
amount.config(validate = "key",validatecommand =  (reg,"%P"))
```

I have understood that the function  `check_the_input_only_allows_digits_only` is registered and for every character the user enters, the function is called and the input is  validated. But why is the `.register` required, couldn't the function be called without `.register` every time the user enters something? What exactly is happening beneath the hood?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The important thing to know is that Tkinter is just a thin wrapper around an embedded Tcl interpreter. That means there are sometimes small compromises due to fundamental differences in the two languages.

### The Tcl Way

When doing input validation in Tcl you specify a Tcl script rather than just a callable function. Tcl will scan the code for special character sequences (such as `%P`, `%S`, etc), and substitute them with information about the data to be validated.

When written in Tcl your code might look something like this:

```
entry .amount -validate key -validatecommand {
    expr {[string is int %P] || [string length %P]==0}
}
```

Or, using a Tcl function:

```
proc check_the_input_only_allows_digits_only {P} {
    expr {[string is int P] || [string length P] == 0}
}
entry .amount \
    -validate key \
    -validatecommand {check_the_input_only_allows_digits_only %P}
```

### The Python Way

Python doesn't have an easy way to pass around code as a string, and even if it did Tcl wouldn't understand it. Instead, in python you must pass a reference to a [callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python) -- typically a reference to a function or method.

In order to pass in those special substitution characters where python expects a callable, you must create a Tcl procedure which acts as a proxy to your python function. This command is created when you call the `register` function.

```
proc = creditor.register(check_the_input_only_allows_digits_only)
amount.config(validate = "key", validatecommand =  (proc,"%P"))
```

If you do not use these characters, you don't need to register the command. For example, the following code is a valid way to call a function that takes no parameters:

```
def check_the_input_only_allows_digits_only():
    ...
amount.config(validate = "key",validatecommand = check_the_input_only_allows_digits_only)
```

Of course, being passed the values for `%P` and the other special character sequences is what makes the validation function so powerful.

Comment: Is there a way to unregister a callback? Because if you have multiple calls to register a callback, it seems nice to unregister it after each use