# Forward method calling in Linear class in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, forward

I am trying to use Linear class of Pytorch module.In this automatically forward method is called once I create an instance of the class.Can anyone explain me from basics (If I can get code of Linear class of pytorch that would be great)

```
from torch.nn mport Linear
model=Linear(in_features=1,out_features=1)
x=torch.tensor([1])
y=model(x)
```

I am not able to understand how model(x) displays the result.As per my understanding model.forward() should display the actual result 
It would be great if someone explain me from basics (Would be great if someone can share the link of code of Linear class in pytorch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[In the source](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/7073ee209000a7781c0c863c4ef39bb3bfdb4932/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L522), you'll see that the `__call__` method of any `Module` in turn calls the `forward` method, so calling `model(x)` in your case is *kind of* like calling `model.forward(x)`, but not exactly, due to the reasons explained [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/any-different-between-model-input-and-model-forward-input/3690/2).

If you're not familiar with the `__call__` method, just know roughly that it makes an object of a class [callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable/115349).

This same question is answered in this [Pytorch forum post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-can-you-call-model-without-specifying-forward-method/24762/2).