# Get a module's attribute's type without importing the module or attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python to do some processing on .py files. These .py files may be from unknown sources so I do not wish to directly run their code (for security), and may not have their dependencies installed anyway. I am analysing these files using python's `tokenize` module and then using the tokens to look at what the types of any NAME tokens are. For a function or class declared in a file you can just do:

```py
import tokenize
# tokenize the source file ...
all_functions = []
for index, token in enumerate(tokens):
    # check the token type
    if token[0] == tokenize.NAME:
        # check the token's string
        if token[1] == "def":
            # the next token is always the name of the function
            all_functions.append(tokens[index + 1][1])
        elif token[1] == "class":
            # as above but for classes ...
```

The problem is that for an imported module I don't know how to tell the difference between a class and a function without seeing its declaration.

Take the following code snippet:

```py
import pathlib
foo = pathlib.Path("some/path")
bar = pathlib.urlquote_from_bytes(b"some bytes")
```

Because this is well written code ([PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compliant), I can *assume* that `pathlib.Path` will be a class because the first character is uppercase and I can *assume* that `pathlib.urlquote_from_bytes` will be a function because it uses lower case words with underscores, however I cannot know for sure without having the module's source code (which may not be the case). Not all of the .py files I receive will necessarily be well written ([PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compliant) so I cannot rely on this.

Is there any other way of finding out whether some python module's attributes are of a given type? A thought I had would be to run `python3 -m py_compile <file>` and then analyse the result .pyc file, but I have never looked into cpython so I don't know if this would actually be helpful or not. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific use case, it turned out I did not need to separate out classes and functions and could wrap them all up as [callables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable). A callable is essentially any instance that has a `__call__()` method, e.g. some method `x(arg1, arg2, ...)` is shorthand for `x.__call__(arg1, arg2, ...)`.

For anyone using older versions of Python it is worth noting that *"this function was first removed in Python 3.0 and then brought back in Python 3.2."*

Further reading:

- [Blog post: Is it a class or a function? It's a callable!](https://treyhunner.com/2019/04/is-it-a-class-or-a-function-its-a-callable/)
- [Python3 docs: Call function](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__)
- [StackOverflow: What is a callable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable)