# Assigning function to a variable

Tags: python, function

Hey guys I was referring to an article on decorators and to explain python closures the author used an example like this.

```
def outer():
    def inner():
        print("Inside inner")

    return inner

foo = outer()
foo() # prints "Inside inner"
```

The part which is confusing to me is **foo** is not explicitly a function but a variable. We use paranthesis just to call a funciton.

Calling variable **foo** as **foo()** should give an error saying no such function exists according to my understanding of functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a "callable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable)

Comment: The return value of `outer()` is a function. That's why it's callable.

Comment: `foo` is just a name for an object like any other name. `inner` is a name for a function.

Comment: A variable can point to a function like it can point to anything else.

Comment: `outer` and `inner` are variables, too - ones whose initial value is a function.  In Python, `def` is really just a very specialized form of assignment statement.

Comment: Take a look at the output of `print(foo)` (not `print(foo())`).

Comment: @BlackBear Thanks for your reference,but I could'nt quite understand the explanation.may be I'm missing something fundamental here.

Comment: Following up on what @BlackBear said, there are other things besides functions which you can call.  E.g., `x = dict()`.

Comment: When I run your code and `print(foo)`, I get `<function outer.<locals>.inner at 0x7fec4175d280>`.

Comment: @DanielWalker sry,my bad  print(foo) returns <function outer.<locals>.inner at 0x7fec4175d280> and print(foo()) executes funtion and also returns NONE.what does it supposed to mean.please bear with me

Comment: The return value of `outer` is a function; namely, the `inner` function you created.  The variable `foo` is assigned to `inner`.  That's why you can call `foo`.  It references the `inner` function.  That's what that print statement meant.  `foo` **is** `inner`.

Answer (score 1):

`foo` is a function.  You created it with `def`.  If you're still unsure, print `type(foo)`.

Remember that Python is an object-oriented language.  That means that "everything is an object", even functions.

You can assign functions to variables, return them as values from other functions, take them as arguments to other functions, etc.

Heck, even modules are objects.  Try this

```
import math

foobar = math
del math

print(foobar.sqrt(5))
```

or even

```
def call_sqrt(x):
    return x.sqrt(5)

import math

print(call_sqrt(math))
```

Comment: This has little to do with being object-oriented; it's more about how Python's data model is defined. Variables are names associated with values, rather than named locations in memory.

Comment: That's true too.