# How can I get hyperparameters about FashionMNIST from dataset?

Tags: pytorch

I am new to deep-learning and I will do something on fashion-mnist.

And I come to found that the hyperparameter of parameter "transform" can be callable and optional and I found that it can be ToTensor().

What can I use as a transform's hyperparameter? Where do I find it?

Actually, I am watching :

https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/datasets.html#fashion-mnist

But I got no answer about it. Help me please. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, `transform` accepts any [`callable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable). As there are a lot of transformations that are commonly used by the broader community, many of them are already implemented by libs such as `torchvision`, `torchtext`, and others. As you intend to work on FashionMNIST, you can see a list of vision-related transformations in [`torchvision.transforms`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html):

> Transforms are common image transformations. They can be chained together using [`Compose`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Compose). Most transform classes have a function equivalent: [functional transforms](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#functional-transforms) give fine-grained control over the transformations. This is useful if you have to build a more complex transformation pipeline (e.g. in the case of segmentation tasks).

You can check more transformations in other vision libs, such as [Albumentations](https://albumentations.ai/docs/examples/pytorch_classification/).