# What python syntax is this?

Tags: python, numpy

I understand that I created a np.poly1d object. But what does it mean by putting it back inside np.poly1d() again?

```
import numpy as np
f = np.poly1d([1, 1, 1])
print(np.poly1d(f))
```

FYI running this script, I got

```
   2
1 x + 1 x + 1
```

Comment: It's ordinary function-call syntax. What `np.poly1d` *does* with a value of `np.poly1d` is not a question of syntax.

Comment: (mkrieger1 more correctly notes it as *call* syntax in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71324952/1126841), as it doesn't necessarily involve an object of type `function`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *call* syntax.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls

`np.poly1d` being the callable and `f` the argument.

`np.poly1d` is a [class](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html), which can be used like a callable to create an *instance* of the class ([What is a "callable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable)).

---

In this particular case, `f` will be interpreted as an array-like of polynomial coefficients, resulting in a new polynomial which is equivalent to `f`, since treating a `np.poly1d` instance as an array results in an array of its coefficients.

```
>>> np.array(f)
array([1, 1, 1])
>>> g = np.poly1d(f)
>>> g == f
True
```

So without knowing more context, using `np.poly1d(f)` instead of `f` seems pointless. It could be useful if the intention was to create a *copy* of a polynomial in order to modify one but not the other, since `f` and `g` are different objects:

```
>>> g is f
False
```

Comment: Not OP, but thanks for the link. As someone that has been learning python, but has dealt with OO and other patterns in many other languages, I'm finding it hard to wrap my head around what "callable" means and its utility. Furiously reading this trying to make sense of it.

Comment: "Callable" is just a term used to avoid using the word "function" in different contexts. A value of type `function` is what a `def` statement or lambda expression produces, and is just one kind of callable value. Other examples are types themselves (you call them in order to get an instance of the type). In Python  instances of *any* type that defines a `__call__` method is callable, and intuitively can be thought of as a function, even if it is not a `function`.

Comment: In some sense, the calling syntax is syntactic sugar for a method call; `foo()` is "short" for `type(foo).__call__(foo)`. (Don't take that idea too far, otherwise you'll create an infinite list of calls, as `type(foo).__call__` itself has a `__call__` method, which has *its* own `__call__` method, etc.)

Comment: @chepner Is this same, conceptually, as an 'iteratable'. Where you can have objects that are collection-like, but not iteratable, and others that are? I'm thinking from an OO standpoint a class generally has a constructor method, and in python it's `__init__()`. In the same sense it can have a `__call__` and an `__iter__`? If I'm thinking about this correctly I can understand why Python is so popular.

Comment: But `id(f.coeffs)` is the same as `id(g.coeffs)`.  `g` is a new `poly1d` instance, but it has the same `coeffs` attribute array.  For some obscure reason (carelessness?), `poly1d` docs uses the `>>> print(np.poly1d(p))` example.

Answer (score 1):

`np.poly1d` appears to be an old, and somewhat non-standard class definition.  There's a note at the start

```
This forms part of the old polynomial API.
```

It is also compiled, so there's no Python class definition to read.  It also does not start with a capital letter, as is normal Python class practice.

You appear to be working from the first example:

```
>>> p = np.poly1d([1, 2, 3])
>>> print(np.poly1d(p))
   2
1 x + 2 x + 3
```

Why they use that print instead of `print(p)` is a mystery.  May be it's just some sloppiness that no one bothered to fix.

`np.poly1d([1,2,3])` makes a `poly1d` class object.

```
In [63]: f = np.poly1d([1, 1, 1])
In [64]: type(f)
Out[64]: numpy.poly1d
In [65]: f
Out[65]: poly1d([1, 1, 1])
In [66]: print(f)
   2
1 x + 1 x + 1
```

`Out[65]` is the `repr` display of this object; `Out[66]` is the `str` display.

```
In [67]: f1 = np.poly1d(f)
In [68]: type(f1)
Out[68]: numpy.poly1d
In [69]: id(f)
Out[69]: 139789855504368
In [70]: id(f1)
Out[70]: 139789855360240
```

Passing a `np.poly1d` object to the class creator appears to make a new `poly1d` object, but with the same attributes.  I don't see that documented.

So in terms of Python syntax, both lines are function calls.  The details of what happens, or not, are internal to the `np.poly1d`.

### edit

Normal class definition:

```
In [75]: class Foo:
    ...:     def __init__(self, x):
    ...:         self.x = x
    ...: 
    ...:     def __repr__(self):
    ...:         return "A Foo <%s>" % self.x
In [76]: g = Foo("xxx")
In [77]: g
Out[77]: A Foo <xxx>
In [81]: type(g)
Out[81]: __main__.Foo
```

[76] uses the class name  to actually call `Foo.__init__` method, returning a `Foo` instance.  `print(g)` or in this (ipython) case `g` displays the instance's `repr`.

With reference to your comments in another answer, I did not define a `__call__` method for the `Foo` class, so its instances are not `callable`.

```
In [94]: g()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [94] in <module>
    g()
TypeError: 'Foo' object is not callable
```

Nor is it iterable

```
In [96]: for x in g:
    ...:     print(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [96] in <module>
    for x in g:
TypeError: 'Foo' object is not iterable
```

In contrast `f`, the `np.poly1d` instance is both callable and iterable:

```
In [97]: f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [97] in <module>
    f()
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'val'

In [98]: f(3)
Out[98]: 13
In [99]: for x in f:
    ...:     print(x)
1
1
1
In [100]: f.coeffs
Out[100]: array([1, 1, 1])
```

That functionality was defined in the compiled code for that class.

## dbl edit

`np.poly1d` docs says the first arg is:

```
c_or_r : array_like
```

Usually that mean the argument is first passed through `np.asarray`.

```
In [147]: np.asarray(f)
Out[147]: array([1, 1, 1])
In [148]: id(_)
Out[148]: 139789855355984
In [149]: id(f.coeffs)
Out[149]: 139789855355984
In [150]: id(f1.coeffs)
Out[150]: 139789855355984
```

The `f1` instance created in [67] has the `coeffs` array as `f`. `np.poly1d(f)` works it is effectively

```
np.poly1d(np.asarray(f))  
np.poly1d(f.coeffs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `np.poly1d`, which is a [`class`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Doing this:

```
f = np.poly1d([1, 1, 1])
```

you are initializing an instance of that class, in other words you are **calling** its `__new__` and its `__init__` methods.

---

When you use `()` after *something*, is because that *something* is a [`callable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable), that may be defined as `@chepner` did in the comments:

> In Python any type that defines a `__call__` method is callable

For example, a function is callable, a method is callable, and also something like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __call__(self):
        ...
```

is callable.

In Python you can check if something is callable with the built-in function `callable`.