# Python Tkinter name [button] is not defined in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make my button change on and off whenever the user clicks on it. But I keep getting a name error. I've tried changing the order of the function and button creation. If I place the button creation above the function then it won't be able to call the function.

Here is my Code:

```
#import all of tkinter and also updated widgets
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import main

#sets up main application window
root = Tk()
root.title("Winstreak Counter GUI")

#creating a content frame (frame widget, hold content of user interface)
#we do this because it'll allow us to control the background color and allow for more themed widgets
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=10, row=10, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
root.columnconfigure(10, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(10, weight=1)

f = open('/Users/ripkoye/Desktop/WinstreakProject/winstreak.txt', 'r')
#store the information into a variable
winstreak = StringVar(mainframe)
winstreak.set(f.read())
#creates a winstreaklabel
winstreaklabel = ttk.Label(mainframe,width=20, padding='5 5 5 5')
winstreaklabel.grid()
winstreaklabel['textvariable'] = winstreak
#assigns the text to the variable named winstreak
f.close()

is_on = True

def switch():
    global is_on

    if is_on:
        buttonOnOff.config(image = off)
        is_on = False
    else:
        buttonOnOff.config(image = on)
        is_on = True

on = PhotoImage(file='on.png')
off = PhotoImage(file='off.png')
buttonOnOff = ttk.Button(mainframe, image=on, width=0.5, padding='5 5 5 5', command=switch())
buttonOnOff.grid()


root.mainloop()
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ripkoye/Desktop/WinstreakProject/gui.py", line 42, in <module>
    buttonOnOff = ttk.Button(mainframe, image=on, width=0.5, padding='5 5 5 5', command=switch())
  File "/Users/ripkoye/Desktop/WinstreakProject/gui.py", line 34, in switch
    buttonOnOff.config(image = off)
NameError: name 'buttonOnOff' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

You calling the `switch` function directly, but you need to give [callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable) object to `command` parameter.

`buttonOnOff` will be created when `ttk.Button` return. But before the `ttk.Button` return, `switch` func will be called because you do `command=switch()`.

You need to modify it like ;

```
buttonOnOff = ttk.Button(mainframe, image=on, width=0.5, padding='5 5 5 5', command=switch)
```

Answer (score 0):

@VeyselOlgun is partly correct, you'll run into an issue with `buttonOnOff`'s `command` parameter - you should change it from `switch()` to `switch`

However, the issue you're having is caused by the fact that `buttonOnOff` is outside the scope of your `switch()` function.

A clean solution is to wrap your button and it's associated command callback in a simple class like so

```
#import all of tkinter and also updated widgets
import tkinter as tk  # star imports are not your friend!
from tkinter import ttk
import main

#sets up main application window
root = tk.Tk()  # properly namespaced w/ 'tk.' prefix
root.title("Winstreak Counter GUI")

#creating a content frame (frame widget, hold content of user interface)
#we do this because it'll allow us to control the background color and allow for more themed widgets
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=10, row=10, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

root.columnconfigure(10, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(10, weight=1)

wsp_path = '/Users/ripkoye/Desktop/WinstreakProject/winstreak.txt'
#store the information into a variable
winstreak_var = tk.StringVar(mainframe)
with open(wsp_path, 'r') as wsp:
    winstreak_var.set(wsp.read())

#creates a winstreaklabel
winstreaklabel = ttk.Label(
    mainframe,
    textvariable=winstreak_var,  # now you can set textvariable here
    width=20,
    padding='5 5 5 5'
)
winstreaklabel.grid()

ButtonOnOff(mainframe)  # call your button class with mainframe as parent


# I like to inherit from tk.Frame as my generic base class
class ButtonOnOff(tt.Frame):  
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)  # init the container frame
        # 'parent' is set to 'mainframe' when you init the class
        self.is_on = True
        self.on = tk.PhotoImage(file='on.png')
        self.off = tk.PhotoImage(file='off.png')
        # create your button
        self.buttonOnOff = ttk.Button(
            self,  # the button is now a child of the ttk.Frame container
            image=self.on,
            width=0.5,
            padding='5 5 5 5',
            command=self.switch  # bind to the 'switch' method below
        )
        button.grid()  # populate the button

    def switch(self):
        if self.is_on:
            self.buttonOnOff.config(image=self.off)
            self.is_on = False
        else:
            self.buttonOnOff.config(image=self.on)
            self.is_on = True
```

*Edit* - I took the liberty of cleaning things up a bit using a [context manager](https://realpython.com/python-with-statement/) to handle the reading of `winstreak.txt`. This handles opening, reading, and closing for you in one fell swoop!

*Another Edit* - I've gotten rid of the star import in favor of `import tkinter as tk` and properly namespaced the necessary classes with `tk.`. See [here](https://code-maven.com/python-avoid-importing-everything) for more info on why star imports can be a headache